# how long is Facebook SDK 2.0 going to work

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I see Facebook released SDK 3.0 on 12/13/2012

How long will apps written with Facebook SDK 2.0 continue to run?  I can't seem to find that anywhere.

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this page](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/13/facebook-sdk-3-0-for-android-and-native-login/) says **June 13, 2013**:

> The latest version of the SDK is backwards compatible for all apps
>   that have integrated SDK 2.0 or higher. Developers should move to SDK
>   3.0 by June 13, 2013, at which time we will end support for issues with SDK 2.0.

Here is a [nice tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/) to help you upgrading your application.